# Sleep function seems to be skipping some of my code

Tags: python, python-turtle

Beginner-ish to python and my sleep function in the function pet_dog is not working properly. I want heart2 to appear when u pet the dog, then sleep for a second, and then it hides. However, instead no heart appears, it just waits a second then adds 1 to the score. I think the sleep function is not pausing before the hideturtle command for some reason and I dont know why.

Tried getting there to be a pause between "heart2.showturtle()" and "heart2.hideturtle()" but instead it is acting as if the pause is between "heart2.hideturtle()" and "score += 1"

```
import turtle
from time import sleep

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("dog petting game!!!")
wn.bgcolor("green")
wn.setup(width = 500, height = 500)
wn.tracer(0)

#person and dogs
shape_heart = ((-6, -10), (-6,-6), (-4, -6), (-4, -4), (-2, -4), (-2, -2), (0, -2), (0,0), (6, 0), (6, -2), (8,-2), (8, -4), (12, -4), (12, -2), (14, -2), (14, 0), (20, 0), (20, -2), (22, -2), (22, -4), (24, -4), (24, -6), (26, -6), (26, -12), (24, -12), (24, -16), (22, -16), (22, -18), (20, -18), (20, -20), (18, -20), (18, -22), (16, -22), (16, -24), (14, -24), (14, -26), (12, -26), (12, -28), (8, -28), (8, -26), (6, -26), (6, -24), (4, -24), (4, -22), (2, -22), (2, -20), (0, -20), (0, -18), (-2, -18), (-2, -16), (-4, -16))
shape_dog = ((0,0), (0, 5), (15, 5), (15, 10), (45, 10), (45, 15), (47, 15), (47, 19), (51, 19,), (51, 15), (54, 15), (54, 19), (58, 19), (58, 15), (60, 15), (60, 0), (50,0), (50, -5), (45, -5), (45, -20), (41, -20), (41, -5), (38, -5), (38, -20), (34, -20), (34, -5), (31, -5), (31, -20), (27, -20), (27, -5), (24, -5), (24, -20), (20, -20), (20, -5), (15, -5), (15, 0))
shape_person = ((0, 100), (0, 110), (35, 110), (35, 135), (60, 135), (60, 110), (95, 110), (95, 100), (60, 100), (60, 20), (52, 20), (52, 60), (43, 60), (43, 20), (35, 20), (35, 100))

turtle.register_shape('heart', shape_heart)
heart1 = turtle.Turtle()
heart1.speed(0)
heart1.left(90)
heart1.shape('heart')
heart1.color('red')
heart1.penup()
heart1.goto(155, 205)
heart1.hideturtle()

heart2 = turtle.Turtle()
heart2.speed(0)
heart2.left(90)
heart2.shape('heart')
heart2.color('red')
heart2.penup()
heart2.goto(-5, 155)
heart2.hideturtle()

heart3 = turtle.Turtle()
heart3.speed(0)
heart3.left(90)
heart3.shape('heart')
heart3.color('red')
heart3.penup()
heart3.goto(-175, 205)
heart3.hideturtle()

turtle.register_shape('dog', shape_dog)
dog1 = turtle.Turtle()
dog1.speed(0)
dog1.left(90)
dog1.shape('dog')
dog1.color('orange')
dog1.penup()
dog1.goto(-200, 150)

dog2 = turtle.Turtle()
dog2.speed(0)
dog2.left(90)
dog2.shape('dog')
dog2.color('orange')
dog2.penup()
dog2.goto(-30, 100)

dog3 = turtle.Turtle()
dog3.speed(0)
dog3.left(90)
dog3.shape('dog')
dog3.color('orange')
dog3.penup()
dog3.goto(130, 150)

turtle.register_shape('person', shape_person)
character = turtle.Turtle()
character.speed(0)
character.left(90)
character.shape("person")
character.color("white")
character.penup()
character.goto(-40, -150)

#functions

def pet_dog():
  global score
  if character.xcor() > 13 and character.xcor() < 31 and character.ycor() > -10 and character.ycor() < 10:
    heart2.showturtle()
    sleep(1)
    heart2.hideturtle()
    score += 1
  if character.xcor() > -156 and character.xcor() < -139 and character.ycor() > 39 and character.ycor() < 60:
    heart3.showturtle()
    score += 1
  if character.xcor() > 174 and character.xcor() < 191 and character.ycor() > 39 and character.ycor() < 60:
    heart1.showturtle()
    score += 1
  pen.clear()
  pen.write(f"Dogs pet: {score}", align = 'center', font = ('Courier', 16, 'normal'))

def character_up():
  y = character.ycor()
  y += 5
  character.sety(y)

def character_down():
  y = character.ycor()
  y -= 5
  character.sety(y)

def character_right():
  x = character.xcor()
  x += 5
  character.setx(x)

def character_left():
  x = character.xcor()
  x -= 5
  character.setx(x)

#Keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(character_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(character_down, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(character_right, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(character_left, "Left")
wn.onkeypress(pet_dog, "p")


#Scoreboard
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color('blue')
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 200)
pen.write("Dogs pet: 0", align = 'center', font = ('Courier', 16, 'normal'))

#Score
score = 0

while True:
  wn.update()

  #Don't let character leave boarders
  if character.ycor() > 120:
    character.goto(character.xcor(), 110)

  if character.ycor() < -270:
    character.goto(character.xcor(), -260)

  if character.xcor() > 185:
    character.goto(180, character.ycor())

  if character.xcor() < -285:
    character.goto(-280, character.ycor())
```

Comment: Post whole code

Answer (score 1):

When you set `wn.tracer(0)` to 0, you have to manually update the screen using `wn.update()`. So adding it like this should work:

```
if character.xcor() > 13 and character.xcor() < 31 and character.ycor() > -10 and character.ycor() < 10:
    heart2.showturtle()
    wn.update()
    sleep(1)
    heart2.hideturtle()
    wn.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @KillRebooted about using `update()` to make your flashing heart visible (and invisible again) +1.  But, I believe you've larger problems with your program design as far as `update()` goes and your use of `while True:` which isn't needed for this particular program.

Below is my rework which addresses these issues along with some style changes and code optimizations:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from time import sleep

# Person and dog shapes
SHAPE_HEART = (
    (-6, -10), (-6, -6), (-4, -6), (-4, -4), (-2, -4), (-2, -2),
    (0, -2), (0, 0), (6, 0), (6, -2), (8, -2), (8, -4),
    (12, -4), (12, -2), (14, -2), (14, 0), (20, 0), (20, -2),
    (22, -2), (22, -4), (24, -4), (24, -6), (26, -6), (26, -12),
    (24, -12), (24, -16), (22, -16), (22, -18), (20, -18), (20, -20),
    (18, -20), (18, -22), (16, -22), (16, -24), (14, -24), (14, -26),
    (12, -26), (12, -28), (8, -28), (8, -26), (6, -26), (6, -24),
    (4, -24), (4, -22), (2, -22), (2, -20), (0, -20), (0, -18),
    (-2, -18), (-2, -16), (-4, -16)
)

SHAPE_DOG = (
    (0, 0), (0, 5), (15, 5), (15, 10), (45, 10), (45, 15),
    (47, 15), (47, 19), (51, 19,), (51, 15), (54, 15), (54, 19),
    (58, 19), (58, 15), (60, 15), (60, 0), (50, 0), (50, -5),
    (45, -5), (45, -20), (41, -20), (41, -5), (38, -5), (38, -20),
    (34, -20), (34, -5), (31, -5), (31, -20), (27, -20), (27, -5),
    (24, -5), (24, -20), (20, -20), (20, -5), (15, -5), (15, 0)
)

SHAPE_PERSON = (
    (0, 100), (0, 110), (35, 110), (35, 135), (60, 135), (60, 110),
    (95, 110), (95, 100), (60, 100), (60, 20), (52, 20), (52, 60),
    (43, 60), (43, 20), (35, 20), (35, 100)
)

SCORE_FONT = ('Courier', 16, 'normal')

score = 0

def pet_dog():
    global score

    if character.distance(22, 0) < 10:
        heart2.showturtle()
        screen.update()
        sleep(1)
        heart2.hideturtle()
        score += 1
    elif character.distance(-147, 49) < 10:
        heart3.showturtle()
        score += 1
    elif character.distance(182, 49) < 10:
        heart1.showturtle()
        score += 1

    pen.clear()
    pen.write(f"Dogs pet: {score}", align='center', font=SCORE_FONT)
    screen.update()

def character_up():
    character.sety(character.ycor() + 5)
    check_boarders()

def character_down():
    character.sety(character.ycor() - 5)
    check_boarders()

def character_right():
    character.setx(character.xcor() + 5)
    check_boarders()

def character_left():
    character.setx(character.xcor() - 5)
    check_boarders()

def check_boarders():
    # Don't let character leave boarders
    if character.ycor() > 120:
        character.sety(110)
    elif character.ycor() < -270:
        character.sety(-260)

    if character.xcor() > 185:
        character.setx(180)
    elif character.xcor() < -285:
        character.setx(-280)

    screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Dog Petting Game!")
screen.bgcolor('green')
screen.setup(width=500, height=500)
screen.tracer(0)

screen.register_shape('heart', SHAPE_HEART)
screen.register_shape('dog', SHAPE_DOG)
screen.register_shape('person', SHAPE_PERSON)

heart1 = Turtle()
heart1.hideturtle()
heart1.shape('heart')
heart1.setheading(90)
heart1.color('red')
heart1.penup()
heart1.goto(155, 205)

heart2 = heart1.clone()
heart2.goto(-5, 155)

heart3 = heart1.clone()
heart3.goto(-175, 205)

dog1 = Turtle()
dog1.shape('dog')
dog1.setheading(90)
dog1.color('orange')
dog1.penup()
dog1.goto(-200, 150)

dog2 = dog1.clone()
dog2.goto(-30, 100)

dog3 = dog1.clone()
dog3.goto(130, 150)

character = Turtle()
character.shape('person')
character.setheading(90)
character.color('white')
character.penup()
character.goto(-40, -150)

# Scoreboard
pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.color('blue')
pen.penup()
pen.sety(200)
pen.write("Dogs pet: 0", align='center', font=SCORE_FONT)

# Keyboard binding
screen.onkeypress(character_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(character_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(character_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(character_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(pet_dog, 'p')

screen.listen()
screen.update()
screen.mainloop()
```

When designing shapes, it's import to consider where the cursor point is (i.e. `(0, 0)`) as that's where functions like `goto()` and `distance()` are relative to.  Usually, if not a kind of cursor, we want it to be the center of the shape.  But not always.  Making the cursor point to be one hand of your person shape makes sense, as does the head of the dog, as that's where the petting action takes place.  If those were the case, then we could compare the distance of the person to the dog, and toss the position tuples:

```
if character.distance(dog2) < 10:
```